# php preg_match and pattern

Tags: php

i have url:
youtube.com/v/NRH2jEyiiLo&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0

And i need only code: NRH2jEyiiLo&hl.

preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);

I use this pattern: `$pattern = '@^([^/v/]+)?([^=]+)@i';`

But why result is: "youtube.com/v/NRH2jEyiiLo"?

How drop "youtube.com/v/", thanks ;)

Comment: Do you have only that URL, or is it embedded in a larger block of other content?

Answer (score 1):

Here's mine... (updated)

```
$url = "youtube.com/v/NRH2jEyiiLo&hl=en&fs=1&rel=0";
preg_match("#[A-Za-z0-9\-\_]{11}#", $url, $video);
echo($video[0]); //NRH2jEyiiLo
```

If you want to embed videos in your webpage, you can try this function... http://webarto.com/57/php-youtube-embed-function

Answer (score 1):

```
  $pattern = '@^([^/v/]+)?([^=]+)@i';
```

using this pattern  then

```
$str= "youtube.com/v/NRH2jEyiiLo";

$newarr = explode('/',$str);

echo $newarr[2];
```

Comment: This will work if nothing is beyond video code, thus not very reliable. What if someone inputs this code http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9beQh1yH5uU&feature=related ?

Comment: I give the answer after pattern matching

Comment: That will work in this case, but not in many others ;) http://www.youtube.com/user/AlJazeeraEnglish#p/u/0/3ZrQYJppX1A , you never know what will user input.

Comment: But is asking for  How drop "youtube.com/v/",

Comment: No, he is asking how to extract video code, but your code also works.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use a character class there, nor the start anchor.

```
$pattern = '@/v/(.*?)&@';
```